# File uploads using jQuery with jquery.fileupload.js fails in Firefox over SSL

Tags: jquery, firefox, ssl, upload, fog

We currently have a setup using FakeS3 and Fog/Carrierwave. In the frontend, we have jQuery file upload (by blueimp) doing the heavy lifting for us, then it gets picked up by our controller and managed on the server.

We are using tunnelss and pow. Tunnelss forwards to port 443, so ALL traffic is encrypted - including uploads and downloads. (https://hostname.dev)

When doing uploads with Chrome and Safari, the uploads are successful and the files are created in the corrected folder for FakeS3. When attempting to use Firefox for the same, we have no response from the server.
Searching through the jqXHR, you find the error: "Uploaded bytes exceed file size" -- I suspect this is because it couldn't connect via $.ajax and jquery.file-upload.js only have this error to report on.

We have spent a lot of time trying to work this out and we need to get this working for Firefox.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

I'm currently running this here as well: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1040080

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-fileupload/8ufWGnX3MSA

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ajax upload images over SSL (with Firefox or other browser):

```
$('.myForm').on('submit', (function(e) {
var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // do something...
        },
        error: function(data) {
            // oops...
        }
    });
});
```